# How to filter out entries that have the same clustering label

Tags: r, dataframe, cluster-analysis

I want to compute the Rand Index between two clusterings I have of a dataset, but I have 80,000 entries in the dataset and the R packages I've found so far that compute the Rand Index cannot actually handle a dataset that large. (For example, the error from mclust is `Error in table(x, y) : attempt to make a table with >= 2^31 elements`)

What I want to do then to reduce the size of the dataset is to filter out entires in my dataset that have the same clustering label. So for example if I have a table

```
   clusteringA | clusteringB
1       a      |      a
2       b      |      b  
3       c      |      b
4       d      |      c
5       d      |      c
6       e      |      d
7       e      |      e
```

Then what I would like to do is to filter out rows 1, 4 and 5 since they will return 1 for all pairwise comparisons. Is there a computationally efficient way to do this? Will doing this actually allow me to compute the Rand Index?

If not, the other possibility I thought of is to break my dataset into chunks and compute the Rand Index separately on those chunks. Does this seem reasonable? I am guessing that there is a fair amount of equal label assignments between the two clusterings; the Rand Index of the first 500 rows is 1.

Comment: I see removing 1, and perhaps 4 or 5, but why both 4 *and* 5? Why not 7?

Comment: 4 & 5 are placed in a cluster together by both method A and B and no other IDs are in that cluster with them. not the case for 7.

Comment: Can you clarify the logic for which rows to keep (or not keep)? For example, a pseudocode logical expression

Comment: @DanHall for(i in 1:nrow(df)) { if i$clusteringA contains the same rows as i$clusteringB then remove i and those rows from table (then skip those rows that were removed) } does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

In clustering, you cannot assume that label a in clustering 1 is the same as label a in clusterings. In the other clustering, this may be label 42 instead.

Because of this, Rand index does *not* compare labels directly, but rather labels of pairs of points. So 4 and 5 have the same label in clustering 1, they are a pair. They also are a pair in clustering 2, so the two clusterings agree that these points should be in the same cluster.

Comment: Yes, which is why I would like to filter out those that have equivalent labelings in clustering 1 and 2. If we were to compare all pairs of my 80k+ row dataset, I would have approx 3.2 billion pairs to compare. Thus I want to filter those points out, as they will return 1 for all pairs that contain them, leading to m(80k-m+1) points less to compare where m is the number of points with equivalent labelings. In my case I think that m is both large (at least n/2) and my dataframe is set up such that the cluster labels are all together, i.e. label a in row 1 will not reappear in any other rows

Comment: Basically I just want a way to compute Rand Index for 80k points. I am working in R but if there is an efficient method in a different language I'm happy to try it.